# Cannot show cell text in a code only custom UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview

I tried to create a custom UITableViewController in code only (without storyboard). The data has already passed in, and verified through tableview:tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath function. But it cannot show them. Please help. Thanks.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Tags:(NSMutableArray *) tags
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.view.frame = frame;
        self.tags = tags;
        [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
     }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tags.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *text = (NSString*)[self.tags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Seems like your tableview isn't visible. Try adding self.view=self.tableView in the first line of your `if(self){}` block.

Comment: Thanks gasparuff. I tried, but it makes no difference. The table lines show as before, but not cell data.

Comment: Why don't you upload your sourcecode somehwere and post the link here? I would take a look on it if you want.

Comment: Thanks!I shared the test project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5e7z9a6xybnekcz/testPrj.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the way you have implemented your code a little bit. I added a TableView in your .xib file and connected it to your viewcontroller. Your `TagsPicker` classes are now not necessary any more.
Find your code here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5602603/testPrj.zip

Comment: Ok. One more thing to add - your Array of tags must be `(strong, nonatomic)` and not `(weak, nonatomic)`.

Comment: Oh, (strong, nonatomic)  is the reason why data did not show up!

Comment: lol that's good :-). I didn't notice it when I tried to make your code work but when I moved the tableview into the .xib I had to create the property in your `ViewController.h`-File and when I copied it from your TagPicker I found that problem, but didn't think that this was the main problem :-)